# Visual Studio 2012 snippet shortcuts not working for SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

I have a custom code snippet that I can access just fine via Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X and then typing 'm' for 'My Code Snippets' and hitting Tab, then typing the first letter of the snippet I want to use, then hitting Enter.

By that time it's almost shorter to just type the real thing out.

I tried assigning a keyboard shortcut to Edit.InvokeSnippetFromShortcut (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard) but although it allows me to assign and save the shortcut, typing the snippets 'shortcut' and then typing the shortcut I assigned to InvokeSnippetFromShortcut does nothing.  It could be because that doesn't show up on the Edit menu where it looks (from googling a bit) like it should be located, so maybe it's not available.

Background: I'm editing a .sql file, so this is a SQL snippet.  Snippet behavior for C#, VB, etc. may not apply here.  My custom snippet has 'sql' as the language (I've tried with sql_ssdt w/ same result).  I just want to be able to type 'foo', hit a single keyboard shortcut, and have the editor replace 'foo' with 'barbaz_some_long_thing_that_is_tedious_to_type'

Has anyone got this working?  If so, how?

Comment: i am using VB and the shortcuts are not working either

Comment: There is a <Shortcut>-tag in the snippet but I can find no information on how to use it. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). You can create an .ahk script to listen for 'hotstrings' (anything typed on the keyboard and then add conditions such as having a certain window open. I use this command to detect Visual Studio

```
Vis()
{
  SetTitleMatchMode 2
  IfWinActive, Microsoft Visual Studio
  {
    return 1
  }
  else
  {
    return 0
  }
}
```

So you can then write this command

```
:*:foo::
if Vis() = 1
{
    SendInput bar
}
else
{
    SendInput foo
}
return
```

Typing `foo` into Visual Studio will run the snippet and sent the input `bar` instead. Typing `foo` into any other window will just output `foo` as normal. Installing AutoHotKey is quick and a lot easier than trying to work within the limitations of what VS can do.

Comment: oh. man.  a system-wide solution like this is something I was looking for a while back and somehow missed this one.  thanks much!

Comment: Glad I could help. AHK is a lifesaver!

Comment: For sure - also since it's a solution for more than just VS.  With larger replacement text strings (like large queries, for example) I noticed it takes a while to send the input.  If you set Clipboard equal to the string, then do Send ^v it will do it instantaneously.  That wipes out the clipboard contents, which I dislike, so I do tempClip := Clipboard before, and Clipboard := tempClip after :)

Comment: @jinglesthula the actual script I use does that, this was just a snippet =)